# How to determine if the firewall is open for given I.P

Tags: c#, ftp

my c# Application access ftp server on the LAN, How do I figure if the FTP Server Firewall is open for my Apllication (I.P) running on another machine.

Comment: Firewall usually block port numbers which can't be tested.  The only way is to try to see if you can send/receive.

Answer (score 0):

use telnet to check if port is open (e.g >telnet ip:port)
the following provides telnet interface fo .net
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/MinimalisticTelnet.aspx